# Un-bold a text with Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a page which runs a timer, and according to that timer, a text item becomes active (bold) and later it gets a strike-through and I am also trying to make it back normal (not bold), and here i stuck.

Text items (each one has its own id):

```
<div id="itm1"> Item 1 text</div>
```

When an item is active:

```
oldHTML = document.getElementById("itm1").innerHTML;
newHTML = "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>" + oldHTML + "</span>";
document.getElementById("itm1").innerHTML = newHTML;
```

The above works and text becomes bold.

Later, I try to strike thorough and unbold

```
    oldHTML = document.getElementById("itm1").innerHTML;
    newHTML = '<span style="text-decoration:line-through; font-weight:normal;">' + oldHTML + "</span>";
    document.getElementById("itm1").innerHTML = newHTML;
```

After this, I get strike through, but bold effect remains.

What am I doing wrong ?
How can I remove the bold effect ?

Comment: _strike thorough and unbold_ the earlier added HTML ?

Comment: use jQuery and .toggleClass() with the two different classes having bold / not bold styles

Comment: You're wrapping more and more `span`s around your text instead of *replacing* the `span`. You shouldn't be doing this at all; you should be setting a style or class on the `itm1` element directly instead of introducing new elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot, gentlemen.

Answer (score 1):

The right solution here will be is to use css classes to style the element

```js
function makebold() {
  document.getElementById("itm1").classList.add('bold');
}

function linethrough() {
  document.getElementById("itm1").classList.add('linethrough');
  document.getElementById("itm1").classList.remove('bold');
}
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.linethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div id="itm1">Item 1 text</div>
<button onclick="makebold()">Bold</button>
<button onclick="linethrough()">Line Through</button>
```

Your script creates the below html, if you see the inner span has the bold attribute which overrides the outer style

```
<div id="itm1">
  <span style="text-decoration:line-through; font-weight:normal;">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;"> Item 1 text</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining my mistake and for the answer ! It works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in deceze's comment you not replace span but wrap it in new span. So you html will looks like this:

```
<div id="itm1"><span style="text-decoration:line-through; font-weight:normal;"><span style='font-weight:bold;'> Item 1 text</span></span></div>
```

So, I think you could to replace your from adding new span around old div's content to something similar to

```
var span=document.getElementById("itm1").querySelectorAll("span")[0];
span.style.fontWeight="normal";
span.style.textDecoration="line-through";
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to your HTML when your javascript is run -

Initial code -

```
<div id="itm1"> Item 1 text</div>
```

After first time your code is run -

```
<div id="itm1"><span style='font-weight:bold;'> Item 1 text</span></div>
```

This makes your **Item 1 text** bold.

Now when your code is run again, it changes the HTML to this -

```
<div id="itm1">
    <span style="text-decoration:line-through; font-weight:normal;">
        <span style='font-weight:bold;'> 
           Item 1 text
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Now in this part, the **font-weight:normal** is overwritten by **font-weight:bold** because of the inner span. This is why you get stroked out text with bold font weight.

Also, this is not the right way to do this. You should use the method suggested by Arun in another answer, or use jQuery [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) if you are already using jQuery in your code.